# Proving $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies (ma)^2 + (mb)^2 = (mb)^2$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Hi I am new to this community and not too sure how to write questions up to par.

How can I prove 
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies (ma)^2 + (mb)^2 = (mb)^2, $$

for all $a,b,c,m$ positive natural numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also, you can check [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you mean $$a^2+b^2=c^2\implies(ma)^2+(mb)^2=(mc)^2$$?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the equation by $m^2$ and use the general rule $x^2y^2 = (xy)^2$.

Comment: sent you an email!

Comment: @Bionic Why would you send an email? You can write another comment instead, especially as TAs don't usually have a lot of time to reply to emails.